# Multiply row based on column information and change column value while iterating through dataframe in pandas / python

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I am having the following dataframe (example of one row):

| quarter | value | distribution | type | ...40 other columns that stay untouched |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024Q2 | 0.5 | {'2024Q1': 91, '2024Q2': 91} | MCF | XYZ |

I want to multiply this one row by the amount of quarters listed in distribution, here 2, and divide the value given by the % distribution of the days in the given quarter, in this example 50%. So the aimed output of this one column would look something like this:

| quarter | value | distribution | type | ...40 other columns that stay untouched |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024Q2 | 0.25 | {'2024Q1': 91, '2024Q2': 91} | MCF | XYZ |
| 2024Q1 | 0.25 | {'2024Q1': 91, '2024Q2': 91} | MCF | XYZ |

2 rows because two quarters are mentioned in the dictionary in distribution column. 0.25 because 0.5 * (91 * (91+91)).

The following code returns the correct amount of rows but does not edit the individual rows as intended, meaning, I get two rows, but the rows are identical, which they should not be. Here is my code:

```
    rows_list = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
        distribution = [[x[0], x[1]] for x in list(row[distribution].items())] # returns [["2024Q1",0.5],["2024Q2",0.5]]
        total_days = sum([x[1] for x in distribution])

        for quarter in distribution:
            percentage = quarter[1] / total_days            
            quarter.append(percentage)

            row[quarter] = quarter[0]                        
            row[value] = row[value] * quarter[2]
            rows_list.append(row)
        
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data=rows_list)
```

When printing out the row, I see that I am editing it, but when adding it to the row_list element it seems like he overrides the quarter in both and applies the %-division two times, returning the following:

| quarter | value | distribution | type | ...40 other columns that stay untouched |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024Q2 | 0.125 | {'2024Q1': 91, '2024Q2': 91} | MCF | XYZ |
| 2024Q2 | 0.125 | {'2024Q1': 91, '2024Q2': 91} | MCF | XYZ |

It is not clear to me why the behaviour is not unique per row but instead applying multiplications two times on, in this example, both rows and only taking the last quarter in the distribution dict.

What am I missing in my loop? How do I make the looping-adding function unique per row iteration? I want to be able to

1. have the division made on multiple columns (arbitrary amount) and
2. get my original df back, I simplified it for StackOverflow - it has 41+ columns and
3. solve this with a loop in order to add / remove multiplications and added logic later on.

Here an example dataframe that could be used:

```
    data = {"quarters":["2024Q1","2024Q3","2024Q4"], "value":[0.5,5,10], "value_2":[0.5,5,10],, "distribution":[{'2024Q1': 91, '2024Q2': 91},{'2024Q3': 30, '2024Q4': 70},{'2024Q4': 91, '2025Q1': 91, '2025Q2': 91}], "type": ["MCF","ABC","DEF"]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df
```

Which should result in the following:

```
| quarter | value | value_2 | distribution | type | ...40 other columns that stay untouched |
|---------|-------|----|----------|------|-------|
| 2024Q2  | 0.25  | 0.25 |{'2024Q1': 91, '2024Q2': 91} | MCF | XYZ |
| 2024Q1  | 0.25  | 0.25 | {'2024Q1': 91, '2024Q2': 91} | MCF | XYZ |
| 2024Q3  | 1.5  | 1.5 | {'2024Q3': 30, '2024Q4': 70} | ABC | XYZ |
| 2024Q4  | 3.5  | 3.5 | {'2024Q3': 30, '2024Q4': 70} | ABC | XYZ |
| 2024Q4  | 3.3  | 3.5 | {'2024Q4': 91, '2025Q1': 91, '2025Q2': 91} | DEF | XYZ |
| 2025Q1  | 3.3  | 3.3 | {'2024Q4': 91, '2025Q1': 91, '2025Q2': 91} | DEF | XYZ |
| 2025Q2  | 3.3  | 3.3 | {'2024Q4': 91, '2025Q1': 91, '2025Q2': 91} | DEF | XYZ |
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible input (`df.to_dict('list')`)

Comment: I added an example df. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the update, can you provide the matching expected output as well?

Comment: Yes and no, unfortunately, the expected output for your input example with two rows was not defined. Well, have a look at my answer below and see if this works, if not then please be explicit ;)

Comment: Sorry, just realized and deleted deleted my comment and adjusted my example accordingly :)

Comment: OK, then I'm waiting for your feedback, hopefully this adresses your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the aimed output. Sharing my code here for visibility or for someone who might have a similar question.

```
data = {"quarters":["2024Q1","2024Q3","2024Q4"], "value":[0.5,5,10], "value_2":[0.5,5,10], "distribution":[{'2024Q1': 91, '2024Q2': 91},{'2024Q3': 30, '2024Q4': 70},{'2024Q4': 91, '2025Q1': 91, '2025Q2': 91}], "type": ["MCF","ABC","DEF"]}
test = pd.DataFrame(data)

rows_list = []
for index, row in test.iterrows(): 
    distribution = row['distribution'] 
    total_days = sum(distribution.values())
    for q in distribution:
        row_tmp = row.copy()
        percentage = distribution[q] / total_days
        row_tmp['value'] = row['value'] * percentage
        row_tmp['value_2'] = row['value_2'] * percentage
        row_tmp["quarters"] = q
        rows_list.append(row_tmp)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data=rows_list) 
print(new_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), then a vectorial division/multiplication and eventually reshape with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)+[`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
# convert dictionaries to columns
tmp = pd.json_normalize(df['distribution'])

# divide by the sum per row (=factor)
# reshape and drop NaN
# quarters to column
# add original columns per index
out = (tmp.div(tmp.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
          .rename_axis(columns='quarters')
          .stack().reset_index('quarters', name='factor')
          .join(df.drop(columns=['quarters']))
       )

# multiply the values by the factor (poping it in the process)
out[['value', 'value_2']] = out[['value', 'value_2']].mul(out.pop('factor'), axis=0)
```

Output:

```
  quarters     value   value_2                                distribution type
0   2024Q1  0.250000  0.250000                {'2024Q1': 91, '2024Q2': 91}  MCF
0   2024Q2  0.250000  0.250000                {'2024Q1': 91, '2024Q2': 91}  MCF
1   2024Q3  1.500000  1.500000                {'2024Q3': 30, '2024Q4': 70}  ABC
1   2024Q4  3.500000  3.500000                {'2024Q3': 30, '2024Q4': 70}  ABC
2   2024Q4  3.333333  3.333333  {'2024Q4': 91, '2025Q1': 91, '2025Q2': 91}  DEF
2   2025Q1  3.333333  3.333333  {'2024Q4': 91, '2025Q1': 91, '2025Q2': 91}  DEF
2   2025Q2  3.333333  3.333333  {'2024Q4': 91, '2025Q1': 91, '2025Q2': 91}  DEF
```

Comment: Thanks, only problem I am having with your solution: my original dataframe has more columns than just three and there are more than just one value column that needs to receive a division. Your solution shorts my original df to only the three columns and I only receive 3 columns instead of 41. 

I would like to be able to apply the division to multiple columns (that I define) and receive the complete df back. As I thought looping would be the best solution, I was simplifying the df to fit SO better.

Comment: Then replace `.join(df[['distribution']])` with `.join(df.drop(columns=['quarter', 'value']))`

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve my case. As adjusted in my post, I would like to be able to (1) keep all columns and (2) make the division on multiple columns, not only on "value". Actually, I would like to solve this example with a loop as (1) I would like to understand in detail what I am doing - your solution might work but is way above my skills atm -, and (2) I would like to improve on my code to understand what I made wrong. Is this not possible?

Comment: I tried your solution and unfortunately, it unexpectably multiplies a lot of redundant rows.

Comment: @Binchentso everything is possible but you have to provide a clear example, which is unfortunately not the case so far (missing columns and just 1 row)

Comment: thanks. You are right, I adjusted my example and clarified what I expect. Sorry, I hope this helps.

Comment: @Binchentso thanks but can you please provide an input with several rows? (like you had done at some point), that is really the unclear part. For instance, if you have 3 input rows and 3 different quarters can you have up to 9 rows in the output? Or should you get 1 row per quarter? If yes, how do you combine the data?

Comment: I added more examples and the expected outcome. Per row, you would get 1 row for each quarter mentioned in the ```distribution```-column. Hence, when you have 3 rows, and they are stating all 3 quarters, you would get 9 rows returned.

Comment: This does not meet my requirement to solve it via a loop and to have the division made on multiple columns, instead of just one. Thanks, I appreciate your work and guess your solution is way superior to what I am aiming for, but I want to avoid copy-pasting something I am not comfortable with / do not fully understand.

Comment: @Binchentso I get that, but pandas is really not designed to work with loops. PLease try to understand the answer and you'll gain valuable know-how. Copy-pasting answers without understanding them should never be an option.

Comment: if I leave out the requirement for loops, I am still missing the requirement to apply the division on multiple columns, not only "value". How would the code needed to be adjusted to fit another "value_2" column?

Comment: There are several option, depending on your expected output please update the example

Comment: I added it to the example in the og post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler example based on your loop. Be careful what variables you update and how you name your variables.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"quarters":["2024Q1","2024Q1"], "value":[0.5,5], "distribution":[{'2024Q1': 91, '2024Q2': 91},{'2024Q3': 91, '2024Q4': 91}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

rows_list = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    distribution = row['distribution']
    total_days = sum(distribution.values())

    for q in distribution:
        percentage = distribution[q] / total_days
        v = row['value'] * percentage
        d = distribution
        rows_list.append({'quarters': q, 'value':v, 'distribution': d})


new_df = pd.DataFrame(data=rows_list)
print(new_df)
```

Comment: Thanks, if I exchange ```rows_list.append({'quarters': q, 'value':v, 'distribution': d})```with ```rows_list.append(row)```I see where my issue occurs. How would I solve this if I have 40+ columns that stay untouched as explained in my example? I assume there might be a more elegant way than writing out all columns, even if they stay untouched?